# Creating Custom Visualizer

Tags: c#, audio, visualizer

I am Trying to make a **Audio visualizer** for a project that will render audio like typical audio debugger

Except rendered as a circle (Some of you may be thinking THATS NOT HOW IT WORKS, but i will explain)

Sorta like this http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/360-player/canvas-visualization.html Thanks Lloyd

So you know the Bar visualizers that show you bass levels ect... those will be the points so each point is assigned one of those values

And as for history each update the preavious one will remain however faded

**So if anyone could tell me about a Libary, similar project (that i could look at the source) or any relavant documentation**

FYI i know about the Debug grapher but as far as i know that only renders the one graph

This Visualizer is all about looks not actual data

I am 100% ready to drop some featuers if they prove difficult

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:
http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/pocket_full_of_html5/#presets/star.js
Using the Star thing Currently investigating source code

Comment: +0.5 for a well written question and +0.5 for a good username.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Soundmanager2 360 Player.. Visualises the sound wave in a circle, using the `canvas` element
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/360-player/canvas-visualization.html

Comment: Thank you was looking to be able to make my own (or edit an existing one)